# Can I make multiple simultaneous phone calls with a single Twilio phone number?

Tags: twilio

I have a Twilio phone number and I need to make multiple phone calls simultaneously. Is it possible to do this with only one phone number, or do I need to purchase multiple phone numbers? If it is possible, what is the maximum number of simultaneous calls that I can make with a single Twilio phone number?

Thank you.

Comment: You can make 1 outgoing call per second and can use the same number for each call. Even if you buy more numbers you are still limited to 1 outgoing call per second. This article covers this limit: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180028-How-fast-can-I-place-or-receive-phone-calls-with-Twilio-#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20each%20Twilio%20account,rate%20of%20one%20per%20second.

Comment: @jassent thank you for posting this link and answer. Could you post it as an SO answer as well? Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make 1 outgoing call per second and can use the same phone number for each simultaneous phone call. Even if you buy more numbers you are still limited to 1 outgoing call per second. This article covers the limits: ["How fast can I place or receive phone calls with Twilio?"](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180028-How-fast-can-I-place-or-receive-phone-calls-with-Twilio-#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20each%20Twilio%20account,rate%20of%20one%20per%20second)